# PHP: How to output list like this: AA, AB, AC, all the way to ZZZY, ZZZZ, ZZZZA etc

Tags: php, algorithm, logic

I'm trying to write a function that'll convert an integer to a string like this, but I can't figure out the logic... :(

```
1 = a
5 = e
27 = aa
28 = ab
etc...
```

Can anyone help? I'm really niffed that I can't wrap my head around how to write this... :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Long list of them [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php):

```
/*
 * Convert an integer to a string of uppercase letters (A-Z, AA-ZZ, AAA-ZZZ, etc.)
 */
function num2alpha($n)
{
    for($r = ""; $n >= 0; $n = intval($n / 26) - 1)
        $r = chr($n%26 + 0x41) . $r;
    return $r;
}

/*
 * Convert a string of uppercase letters to an integer.
 */
function alpha2num($a)
{
    $l = strlen($a);
    $n = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++)
        $n = $n*26 + ord($a[$i]) - 0x40;
    return $n-1;
}
```

Comment: +1. Though you need to subtract one from the initial value of $n in num2alpha, and not subtract 1 in the end in alpha2num, in order to match the OP's specification that 1 = A.

Comment: good call -- code was taken straight from the php.net site as a good reference for the concept

Comment: why it doesn't work for a large number like this: num2alpha(20160504123435)?

Answer (score 7):

I'll add this answer to sum up the comments regarding the misuse of base-26.

A common first reaction when confronted with this problem is to think *"There are 26 letters, so this must be base-26! All I need to do is map each letter to its corresponding number"*.

**But this is not base-26.** It's easy to see why: there is no zero!

In base-26, the number twenty-six is the first number with two digits, and is written "10". In this counting system,  twenty-six has a single digit, "Z", and the first two-digit number is twenty-seven.

But what if we make A=0, ..., Z=25? This way we have a zero and the first two-digit number becomes twenty-six. So far so good. How do we write twenty-six now? That's "AA". But... isn't A=0? Ooops! A = AA = AAA = "0" = "00" = "000".

Comment: Just trying to wrap my head round this. Wouldn't 26 just be BA, not AA if A=0.

Comment: @Paystey Yes, if *this was base-26*. But the number that follows 25 (Z) in this scheme is AA.

Comment: Yes, true, just trying to get my head around base 26 made entirely ofletters. It works. But that's not what this is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Well, you're pretty much converting from base 10 to base 26. Base 10 has digits 0-9, whereas base 26 can be expressed with "digits" A-Z. Conversion from base-10 is easy - see e.g. this: http://www.mathsisfun.com/base-conversion-method.html</strike>

Edit: actually, base-26 fails to account for multiple equivalent ways to write 0 ( 0 = 00 = 000).

Comment: No it isn't. Say, "digit" A is equivalent to "digit" 1, B is 2, and so on. So we have 1,2,3,4,...,Z,11,12,13,...,1Z,21. Not good. Ok, let's try A = 0, B = 1, etc. We have 0,1,2,3,4,...,Z,00,01,02,...,0Z,10,. Nope, not base-26 at all.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: I did __not__ say base-36, nor 0-9+A-Z; you seem to be using that. Pray tell, how many letters are there in the English alphabet, from A to Z? Last time I checked, there were 26 of them. A = 1,B = 2, C = 3, ..., X = 24, Y = 25, Z = 26, AA = 27 ( 26^1 *A + 26^0 *A ), AB = 28 ( 26^1 * A + 26^0 * A ), AC = 29, AD = 30, etc etc. You may have been confused by base-16, which uses 0-9+A-F, this is a slightly different case.

Comment: You missed my point: 1,2,3,4,...,<whatever the last digit is>,11,12,13. You just missed the number "10" (aka 26)! See, in base 26, the number 26 has **two digits**, just like 2 in base 2 and ten in base ten.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: Looks like I did miss it. If A = 0, then also A = AA = AAA = AAAA = AAAAA = 0. You are right, thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [`base_convert`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) to convert your numbers to a 26 base:

```
base_convert(35, 10, 26);
```

That gives you the individual components in numbers from `1 - p`, so 35 becomes `19` (1 * 26 + 9). Then you have to map the individual components to your desired set, so 1 => a, 9 => i, a => j, etc. and `19` becomes `ai`.

Comment: Problem is, 26 => 1 * 26 + 0 => 10 in base 26. Ooops, how do you map the 0? No, this kind of Excel-ish counting **is not base 26**.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes Interesting, you're right, there´s no base at all. I wonder how the OP accounts for 0...

Answer (score 0):

```
void convert(int number)
{

        string str = "";

    while(number)
    {
        char ch;
        ch = (number - 1) % 26 + 65;    
        str = ch + str;
        number = (number-1) / 26;
    }

    cout << str << endl;
}
```