# PHP int to string

Tags: php, string, int, typing

I know that in PHP you can declare a variable A and then if you increment it in a loop it will go A,B,C,....X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC

Is there any php function to convert an integer to the corresponding string in that format

Comment: Heres how:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554369/php-how-to-output-list-like-this-aa-ab-ac-all-the-way-to-zzzy-zzzz-zzzza

Is called "Base26"... the quotes because uses A-Z as symbols (that somewhat unusual).

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavigesimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started with Tor P's answer and I think this works as desired:

```
function numToString($i) {
    if($i < 26) {
        return chr(65 + $i);
    } else {
        $i -= 26;
        $r = $i % 26;
        return numToString($i - $r).chr(65 + $r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to that format is [base_convert](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php), but it uses the 0-9A-Z charset.

You can use base 26, and then shift the charset.

Comment: It is close, but really not base 26... I like the idea, but I am not sure how you would make it work.

Comment: Ah... So you do a base conversion and then str_replace with two 26 element arrays? That would definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

use the chr function with the int transformed into an ascii code (capital letters go from 65-90), so 65+i, to use i >= 26 you have to do one letter at a time

so, something like this...

```
function noToString($i) {
  if($i < 26) return chr(65+$i);
  else return noToString($i-26).chr(65+$i%26);
}
```