# Id to userfriendly characters

Tags: php

I want to create a userfriendly system to make users enter a certain id:

```
id 1-26: A-Z
27: AA
28: AB
    ...
    ...
    ZZZ
```

I tried several ways to achieve this but I get random characters...

```
$counter = 7;
do {
    $temp = floor($id / (26^$counter)) % 26; 
    $counter--;
    echo($temp.' ');
} while($counter > 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for edit! (Typo in title)

Comment: Where does `$id` come from? Is it a number that the user enters?

Comment: id 27 should be AA if I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes, 27 = AA, 28 = AB... The id isn't user input but comes from the db.

Comment: You're giving yourself the same problem as Excel column names, in that it's not as simple as converting to base 26. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297213/translate-an-index-into-an-excel-column-name

Comment: Just ... `AA` is "user-friendly", where `27` isn't?!? Where is the difference?

Comment: For a PHP solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5554413/263057

Comment: @KingCrunch yes, imo YRX is more userfriendly than 391023 but indeed for smaller numbers this isn't the case...

Comment: @Ferdau "more userfriendly" is quite relative when you taking into account, that a user can't read both ;) (`HJDFSH` <=> `98432`?)

Comment: Well wouldn't HJDFSH be like 983712349108? It will be shorter and believe but thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping Excel column name to numeric order is kind of a crappy thing, because there's no `0` in A-Z...

Anyway, I did come up with two functions to convert them back and forth:

```
function calcCol($col) //character to number
{
    if(is_numeric($col)) return intval($col);
    $col=array_reverse(str_split(strtoupper(preg_replace("/[^a-z]/i","",$col))));
    $num=0;
    foreach($col as $i=>$ch)
    {
        $num+=(ord($ch)-ord('A')+1)*pow(27,$i);
    }
    $num-=ceil($num/27)-1;
    return $num;
}
function getCol($col) //number to character
{
    if(preg_match("/^[a-z]+$/i",$col)) return strtoupper($col);
    $col=abs(intval($col));
    $col+=ceil($col/26)-1;
    $str="";
    while($col>0)
    {
        $tmp=$col%27;
        $str=chr($tmp-1+ord('A')).$str;
        $col=floor($col/27);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Explanation:

Consider A-Z as a **27-based** numeric system with a missing/hidden `0`;

And after converting from character to number, removes those hidden `0`s by counting how many 27 is "counted" (`ceil($num/27)`);

And before converting from number to character, add those hidden `0`s back by counting how many 26 is "counted" (`ceil($col/26)`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a base-converting problem, but there's a little trick.

First we consider `'A'` as `1`, so `'AA'` or `'AAA'` could make sense, and `'B'` as `2`, `'C'` as `3`.., but what about `'Z'`? No, `'Z'` is not 26, the trick here is to consider the `'Z'` as `'A0'`, and every time we find a `0` when in converting, we write it down as `'Z'`, and throw a `'A'` away(by subtracting 1).

so we have the following code:

```
function num2user( $num )
{
    $s = "ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $ret = "";
    while( $num > 0 )
    {
        $m = $num % 26;
        $ret = $s[$m].$ret;
        $num = floor($num / 26);
        if( $m == 0 ) $num = $num - 1;
    }
    return $ret;
}

for( $i = 1 ; $i < 128 ; $i++ )
{
    echo "$i=".num2user($i)."\n";
}
```