# In PHP, how can I convert an Excel style column name into a number?

Tags: php, excel

Using PHP, how can I convert an Excel style column name, like "CF", into a number (CF=84)?
This question specifically pertains to PHP. Please don't "dupe" this with an answer for a different language.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554369/php-how-to-output-list-like-this-aa-ab-ac-all-the-way-to-zzzy-zzzz-zzzza

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel column number from column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106465/excel-column-number-from-column-name)

Comment: @nogad, possibly but when I was searching for a solution I did not find that question because it is for a different utility.

Comment: @MarianD, It is not a duplicate of that question. This Q&A specifically is related to PHP use.

Comment: Oh, you are right, please accept my apology.

Answer (score 1):

Try these functions.

```
/**
 * Convert Excel style column names into numbers.
 * @param string $column Excel style column name like AA or CF
 * @return integer Number with A being 1 and AA being 27
 */

function alpha2num($column) {
    $number = 0;
    foreach(str_split($column) as $letter){
        $number = ($number * 26) + (ord(strtolower($letter)) - 96);
    }
    return $number;
}

/**
 * Access array value with Excel style column name.
 * @param array $array The array to access
 * @param string $column Excel style column name like AA or CF
 * @return mixed Value found at the column
 */
function alpha_col($array, $column){
    $i = alpha2num($column) - 1;
    return isset($array[$i]) ? $array[$i] : false;
}
```

Comment: [PHPExcel does it a bit differently, if you're interested.](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1c8c2379ccf5ab9dd7cb46be965821d22173bcf4/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php#L790)

Comment: I saw that but to me it looked like a dirty method, albeit robust.

Comment: I just thought you might be interested in some of their observations on `ord` and `strtolower` performance impacts. I agree your way looks neater.

Comment: If you were building a library, like PHPExcel did, I would be more concerned with performance. When I wrote the functions I was working on a simple CSV import system.

Comment: Makes sense. I didn't intend to be critical. I just thought you'd find it interesting if you hadn't seen it already.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Note: the code PHPExcel uses in the link above is no longer valid in newer PHP versions - 'Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated'